# AlertDialog setOnShowListener never called

Tags: java, android

I am using a slightly different approach in order to keep the dialog open when a button is pressed:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewTableActivity.this);
builder.setTitle(R.string.addComponent);

final EditText titleText = new EditText(NewTableActivity.this);
titleText.setHint(R.string.title);

builder.setView(titleText);
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i){
        dialogInterface.cancel();
    }
});
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null);
final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener(){
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface){
        Log.i("TEst", "Doung");
        Button button = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    }
}
```

The dialog is opened a little lower (this works too), but the Log is never called

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't onShow in my custom dialogfragment being invoked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522103/why-isnt-onshow-in-my-custom-dialogfragment-being-invoked)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewTableActivity.this);
builder.setTitle(R.string.addComponent);

final EditText titleText = new EditText(NewTableActivity.this);
titleText.setHint(R.string.title);

builder.setView(titleText);
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        dialogInterface.cancel();
    }
});
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null);
final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        Log.e("TEst", "Doung");
        Button button = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    }
});

alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: @lucas Please replace this text, because I have tested this code & Its working good in My App.

Comment: make sure you using android.support.v4.AlertDialog