# .setOnShowListener not appearing on fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I'm new to android and I've watched tutorials online on creating alert dialogs with countdowns but i can't seem to use the .setOnShowListener on my alert box.

[image: I made this on a Fragment]

[image: Output Reference]

I tried to transfer it to the homepage activity but the button is on the 1st fragment

Comment: Check if this helps!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214856/alertdialog-setonshowlistener-never-called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might solve your problem.

```kotlin
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding.button2.setOnClickListener {
            builder.setTitle("Alert!")
            builder.setMessage("Are u OK?")
            builder.setCancelable(true)
            builder.setPositiveButton("yes") {
                    dialog, which ->
                    //do something
                }
            builder.setNegativeButton("No") {
                    dialog,which ->
                    //do something
                }
            builder.create().setOnShowListener { 
                //do something
            }
            builder.show()
        }
```

You cannot call `setOnShowListener()` method without calling `create()` first

Please mark it as the answer if it solved your problem, or ask me where it's going wrong after this.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong call of the method, try this

```
builder.setOnShowListener(this);
```

Or you can simply write your call inside the method like this

```
 builder.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

  @Override
public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
  // your code
}
```

});